# How do import python packages and develop packages in a nested directory structure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, package, setuptools

I have a repository that contains two modules that are separate but I'd like to keep together for the purposes of git etc. This is what the directory structure looks like:

```
basedir
      |
      |- moduledir1
      |           |- setup.py
      |           |- my_module1
      |                       |- __init__.py
      |                       |- my_module1.py
      |                       |- subpackage1
      |                                    |- imports_my_module1.py
      |- moduledir2
                  |- setup.py
                  |- my_module2
                              |- __init__.py
                              |- my_module2.py
                              |- subpackage2
                                           |- imports_my_module2.py
```

If I am in `imports_my_module1.py` I can't import my_module1, for example this doesn't work:

```
from my_module1.my_module1 import SomeClass
```

However if I modify the directory structure by adding an `__init__.py` file to the moduledir1 directory to look like this:

```
basedir
      |
      |- moduledir1
      |           |- __init__.py
      |           |- setup.py
      |           |- my_module1
      |                       |- __init__.py
      |                       |- my_module1.py
      |                       |- subpackage1
      |                                    |- imports_my_module1.py
      ... the rest is identical to above
```

Now I can do:

```
from moduledir1.my_module1.my_module1 import SomeClass
```

with no issues. However everything is messed up when I actually install the module because it can't find `moduledir1` after being installed. Also ideally `moduledir1` just shouldn't be the in the import path at any point.

Is there a way to resolve this? Or is this directory structure hopelessly impossible to work with?